# Generic code for Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create one loop that will access and push data from three arrays in JavaScript:

```
var tempArray1=new Array();
var tempArray2=new Array();
var tempArray3=new Array();
```

I tried following code:

```
for(var j=1; j<4; j++) {
  var res = new Array();
  var str = 'tempArray' + j;
  res = str.split(" ");
}
```

but with this nothing happened.

Please help me to create generic code.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the arrays?

Comment: Please review [ask]. Question is not clear and you haven't provided any expected results. Broken code is not a good substitute for  a proper explanation of what that code is expected to do

Comment: Also something did happen.. errors were thrown in your console and you ignored them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Brief

```
var res=[...tempArray1,...tempArray2,...tempArray3]
```

or more dynamic

```
var res=eval('[...tempArray1,...tempArray2,...tempArray3]') // since it is generic
```

## DEMO :

```js
var tempArray1=["I","love","JS"],tempArray2=["But","I'm"],tempArray3=["a crazy","JS","Programmer"]

function range(size){ /* for you case ,it returns : [1,2,3] */
    return Array.from({length:size},(v,k)=>k+1)
}

function generate(size){
 return eval('[...'+range(size).map((i)=>'tempArray'+i).join(',...')+']')
}

console.log(
  generate(3) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempArray1 =[1,2,3];
var tempArray2 =[4,5];
var tempArray3 =[6];

function myConcat(){//This is the generic method
  var result =[];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result = result.concat(arguments[i]);
  }
  return result;
};

var conctenatedArray = myConcat(tempArray1,tempArray2,tempArray3);
console.log(conctenatedArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8jwyzn0x/

**

> OR

**

It would be good, if you wrap those array in a container object.

```
function myConcat(container){//This is the generic method
  var result =[];
  for(var i in container){
   result = result.concat(container[i]);
  }
  return result;
};

var arrayContainer ={};
arrayContainer.tempArray1 =[1,2,3];
arrayContainer.tempArray2 =[4,5];
arrayContainer.tempArray3 =[6];

 var conctenatedArray = myConcat(arrayContainer);
 console.log(conctenatedArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8jwyzn0x/1/